# Three vertices of a triangle lie on $y^2=x^3$

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

> If ${P(a,b),Q(c,d),R(m,n)}$ are the centroid, orthocenter, circumcenter respectively of a scalene triangle with  vertices on the curve $y^2=x^3$, then find the value of $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{m}{n}$$

---

I know that the centroid, orthocenter and circumcenter lie on the straight line and centroid divides orthocenter and circumcenter in ratio $2:1$. Thus

$$a=\frac{2m+c}{3},b=\frac{2n+d}{3}$$ As you can see I am not able to use  $y^2=x^3$.

---

I think there is some trick involved!

Comment: the coordinates are in the form $(x, x^\frac{3}{2})$ so substitute the letters in accordingly

Comment: @user29418 No they are not. Only vertices lie on that curve. P, Q, and R do not.

Comment: Parameterization of curve : $t^2, t^3$. Desired expression is sum of inverse slopes of three lines passing through origin and one center each. These intercept off the Euler line, segments in ratio $1:2$ which I'm not sure how to utilize.

Comment: What's the source of problem?

Comment: @cosmo5 a fiitjee mock exam

Comment: There's a shortcut, use the vertices as (0,0), (1,1), (-1,1)....oh well, orthocenter,circumcenter would be in a funny position

Comment: Maybe by considering this curve (semicubic parabola) as the evolute of a parabola (https://mathcurve.com/courbes2d.gb/parabolesemicubic/parabolesemicubic.shtml#) ?

Comment: Can't be a unique non-zero value, as if it were, reflection of the triangle about X axis would give the negative of it also as an answer.

Comment: The value of  $$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{m}{n}$$ depends on the triplet we consider.

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}{} G=(a,\sqrt{a^3}) & H=(c,\sqrt{c^3}) & O=(m,-\sqrt{m^3}) \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \frac{x_{H}-x_{G}}{x_{G}-x_{O}}=2 & \frac{c-a}{a-m}=2 & a=\frac{2m+c}{3} \end{array}$

$\begin{array}{} \frac{y_{H}-y_{G}}{y_{G}-y_{O}}=2 & \frac{\sqrt{c^3}-\sqrt{a^3}}{\sqrt{a^3}+\sqrt{m^3}}=2  \end{array}$

$\frac{\sqrt{c^3}-\sqrt{(\frac{2m+c}{3})^3}}{\sqrt{(\frac{2m+c}{3})^3}+\sqrt{m^3}}=2$

One solution that checks the system is:

$m=\frac{1}{2}\left( 2+\sqrt{6+\sqrt[3]{9}}-\sqrt{12-\sqrt[3]{9}}+\frac{30}{\sqrt{6+\sqrt[3]{9}}}  \right) ·c$

$\begin{array}{} m=α·c & α≈0.158873884116  \end{array}$

numerically checking the value of the expression k

$k=\frac{a}{b}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{m}{n}$

$k=\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}$

$\begin{array}{} m=α·c & a=\frac{1+2α}{3}  \end{array}$

$k=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{1+2α}}+1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{α}}   \right)·\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} ≈\frac{-2·10^{-15}}{\sqrt{c}}$

Indicating that the value of k is zero

Proof:

$k=\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{1+2β}}+1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{β}}   \right)·\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}} =0$

$\begin{array}{} \text{Solving} & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{1+2β}}+1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{β}}=0 & β=0.158873884146 \end{array}$

β is equal to α which is the solution of the initial system.

[image: curve]